# javascript split() method adds \r to the end of the string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make an array with some fetched data and make a new set with it
but the strings that are made have \r at the end of them:

```
export const WordSetFn = async () =>{
    let wordSet;
    await fetch(wordsSet).then((resp) =>
        resp.text()
    ).then((resp) =>{
        const wordSetArray = resp.split("\n")
        wordSet = new Set(wordSetArray)
    })
    return {wordSet};
} // word set would look like this: {"above\r",...}
```

and the txt that I'm fetching the data from is a bunch of words that are below each other
each in a line like this

```
aback
abase
abate
abbey
abbot
abhor
abide
abled
abode
abort
...
```

now why does it make \r at the end of the strings after each word and what does \r do?

Comment: It does not add `\r` try to split by `\n\r`

Comment: If the response is based on a file stored in Windows, it's likely to contain `\r\n` for new line rather than `\n`, so if you split by `\n`, the `\r` will remain. The `\r` was not added by `split`, but by whichever editor saved the file with Windows line endings. It's possible to handle both `\n` and `\r\n` by using RegEx like `resp.split(/\r?\n/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` is a carriage return, `\n` is a line feed, `\r\n` is a carriage return plus line feed.